# Pygsheets is not working from last 3-4 days

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-developers-console, pygsheets

From last 3-4 days pygsheets is not working. I don't have any problem till now and I am using from last 4-5 months. May be there is problem with google oauth. I observed that the consent screen from which authorization code is copied and pasted in python program is changed.[image: Earlier this much description is not there.] I even created a new account and created a fresh project and fresh app in oauth consent screen. Enabled apis and done all that are necessary. The authorization code is generating but when I enter the code in python program I am getting a error as follows.

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000015978E3E130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I used a simple code

```
gc = pygsheets.authorize(client_secret='C:\\Users\\asapu\\AppData\\Roaming\\gspread\\TEST\\credentials.json',
                         credentials_directory='C:\\Users\\asapu\\AppData\\Roaming\\gspread\\TEST')
sh = gc.open("TEST SHEET")
print(gc, sh)
```

I don't understand what google has changed.

Comment: I just tried to auth a script with pygsheets and it's working fine. Are you using some VPN? If the issue persists please create a bug report in the pygsheets repo.

Comment: Please look into my test account and see what I did wrong. username: piccaloalerts@gmail.com password: Test4321@